Ошибка при обращении к БД в Jmix
Смотрю курс по jmix на https://stepik.org/course/190140/syllabus. В курсе создается сущность Project, все делаю пошагово, но когда запускаю приложение и перехожу на экран, где происходит обращение к этой сущности выходит ошибка:

Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object
not found: PROJECT

. Тоже самое и при обращении к другим сущностям. Может кто-то сталкивался с такой ошибкой? Как исправляется? В курсе ничего не сказано об этом.
